# Redirect DNS and URL from one domain to another?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns

I have two virtual servers. Each is running a website.

VPS #1. IP: 1.1.1.1 Domain: example1.com on Apache2
VPS #2. IP: 2.2.2.2 Domain: example2.com on Apache2

example2.com domain is replacing example1.com domain. I want to cover all existing links pointing to example1.com.

If I place the following code in the .htaccess file on example.com's website:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example1.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example1.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Everything works so far. However, this means that I have to keep the VPS for example1.com up and running, and I want to eventually shut that server down.

What will be the easiest way for domain #1 and domain #1 to exist on the same VPS and have all requests for domain #1 redirected to domain #2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a virtual host on your VPS #2 apache server for the example1.com domain
2. In the document root for this domain, move those mod_rewrite rules you have into an htaccess file
3. Change the DNS for example1.com to point to 2.2.2.2

After a few days, after all the DNS caches have been refreshed to use 2.2.2.2, you can shut down VPS #1.

Comment: What will happen to links that exist in the real world that point to example1.com?  Like links on Facebook that point to articles on example1.com that are now on example2.com?

Comment: @stevensheeley they will get redirected to example2.com, and will continue to do so until you stop running the vhost on vps #2